# How to make a computational node offline in Microsoft HPC cluster when the running job on the computational node fails?

Tags: c#, cluster-computing, hpc

If one node has an issue and the executable fail in that machine, most of the jobs in the queue will fail.  This is happening because the first job is declared failed quickly,  the machine becomes available again and takes another job which fails again quickly. Then, this continues until the queue becomes empty and all job fails.

Is there any mechanism to isolate a node with a problem so that the other nodes can process the remaining jobs. Something like declaring a node faulty. Does HPC support that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to add the host to the excluded nodes list to avoid tasks being submitted for this host.

This is how it works:

> If a job owner or a cluster administrator notices that tasks in a job
>   consistently fail on a particular node, they can add that node to the
>   Excluded Nodes job property. When the Excluded nodes limit is reached,
>   attempts to add more nodes to the list fail. For more information,
>   [see Set and Clear Excluded Nodes for Jobs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff919483(v=ws.11).aspx).